# How to keep checkbox state in google visualisation table with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using google visualisation table and adding check boxes in the list. I want to select some rows with check boxes and perform some action on those selected row. But when the `sort` or `page` event is called the table is redrawn and the check boxes goes unchecked.

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rishad/a4ach2k1/)

How can I keep the checkbox state after the table is sorted or page is changed?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the event is called, you can do something like this to save the `checked` state of you checkboxes:

```
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#table_div input[type=checkbox");
  var checkboxesState = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function(){
      checkboxesState[this.getAttribute("id")] = this.checked;
    });
  }
```

And after the event is called, restore it:

```
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function(ev) {
       //Needed, since the whole table DOM will change
       checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("#table_div input[type=checkbox");
          for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxesState[checkboxes[i].getAttribute("id")]){
              checkboxes[i].checked = checkboxesState[checkboxes[i].getAttribute("id")];
            }
          }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible for you to edit the fiddle ?

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: Done, I edited my answer with the necessary changes as well.

Comment: Thanks, it helped but it does not work for 'page' event for some reason

Comment: How is the `page` event triggered? I assume it's not possible on that fiddle.

Comment: you can change the page size to 2 and try it if you want :)

Comment: There was one other thing I had to account for, the fact that on page change all the table DOM gets refreshed, so you will need new listeners on the checkboxes, as I did here https://jsfiddle.net/a4ach2k1/41/